# Anyone familiar with "consets"?

Tags: shopping

I just saw a Facebook ad for consets.com.

They claim to do a "warehouse clearance", "today only" of genuine LEGO,

Their prices are suspiciously low, though, even for "bootLego" / "fake Lego" standards.

May I presume these are scammers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## If you see steep discounts on many LEGO sets, it's a scam.

LEGO and their retail partners rarely discounts their products to 50% or more, and when they do it's rarely on current products. A site offering such steep discounts on a large variety of current products simply isn't credible.

You *might* find substantial discounts on knockoff brand sets, but if they present them as genuine branded LEGO products (with the LEGO logo), that's clearly still a scam.

## Yes, *con* sets lives up to the name, it's a phishing scam.

If you try to make an order (using fake data!) you will find a page on the website asking you to enter your credit card information.

> [image]

This payment information does not go through a 3rd party payment processing website (those images mean nothing), they expect you to enter your credit card information directly into their system.

Very few legitimate merchants are allowed to collect credit card information directly, because it's difficult and expensive to secure the data and pass the necessary security audits.

Not only will you not get the products, your payment information will be used by criminals.

## Known issue.

On a side note many LEGO fan communities and LEGO themselves are aware of these scams and they've been going on for some time (no doubt they will ramp up for Black Friday). Unfortunately between the shell games these scammers play* and Facebook's general inaction against malicious and dishonest advertisers they will probably continue.

* Often the advertising targets a specific region with a unique domain for that region, and if you visit the website from an IP address outside that targeted region you will see a generic clothing shopping site (in an effort to evade detection).

Comment: Great answer, I usually report those Ads to the social media website owned by Mark but that seems to be useless, FB doesn't give a flying fudge about it.

Comment: @HenriquedeSousa Why would they do anything about it (otherwise than continuing to show them), they get advertising income from those ads :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you may. These scam sites pop up daily, especially around the holidays.